# Organizing a JSON result with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, object

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
data=[{"name":"John Smith",
       "favorites":{"color":"orange",
                    "city":"Paris"}},
      {"name":"Jane Baker",
       "favorites":{"color":"red",
                    "city":"San Francisco"}},
      {"name":"Tommy Jones",
       "favorites":{"color":"blue",
                    "city":"Paris"}}]
```

I'd like to go through these results with jQuery and restructure the data where each person goes into a favorite city object (creating a new object if it's unique or putting into an existing object if it isn't). Like this...

```
data=[
    {"city":"Paris",
        {{"name":"John Smith",
          "color":"orange"},
         {"name":"Tommy Jones",
          "color":"blue"}}
    },
    {"city":"San Francisco",
        {{"name":"Jane Baker",
          "color":"red"}}
    }]
```

Can someone please help me how to go about this?

Comment: Your expected _data_ is not valid JavaScript, apart from that what have you tried so far?

Comment: I removed the _data_ to avoid confusion...it was there to infer that it was coming from an $.ajax call. I have not gotten far with this because I haven't found yet how to detect if a value in the city key exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method results in the following object

```
{"Paris":[
    {"name":"John Smith","color":"orange"},
    {"name":"Tommy Jones","color":"blue"}],
"San Francisco":[
    {"name":"Jane Baker","color":"red"}]
}
```

here is the code

```
var data=[{"name":"John Smith","favorites":{"color":"orange","city":"Paris"}},
{"name":"Jane Baker","favorites":{"color":"red","city":"San Francisco"}},
{"name":"Tommy Jones","favorites":{"color":"blue","city":"Paris"}}];

var cityData = {};

data.map(function(person){
    if(person.favorites.city in cityData) {
        cityData[person.favorites.city].push(
            {
                "name" : person.name,
                "color" : person.favorites.color
            }
        );
    } else {
        cityData[person.favorites.city] = 
            [{
                "name" : person.name,
                "color" : person.favorites.color
            }];
    }
}, cityData);

console.log(cityData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(cityData));
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it something like this:

```
var newData = [], tempData = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  // Extract all the information we need.
  var person = data[i],
      cityName = person.favorites.city,
      personObj = {name: person.name, color: person.favorites.color };

  if (tempData[cityName]) {
    tempData[cityName].people.push(personObj); 
  } else {
    tempData[cityName] = { people: [personObj] };
  }
}

// Sort the data into the required format
for (var city in tempData) {
  var people = tempData[city].people;
  newData.push({ city: city, people: people });
}
```

Comment: Going to give this a go! **Thank you.** I'll let you know!

Comment: For some reason this loop isn't recognizing an existing city name. http://goo.gl/t9liC

Comment: That's weird. I'll have a look.

Comment: Updated it. Should sort properly now.

Comment: **That does!** Thank you, Ross.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here ya go! (It's not as good as Ross Penman's though!)
http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/UzpfQ/

```
var people =[
    {"name":"John Smith","favorites":{"color":"orange","city":"Paris"}},
    {"name":"Jane Baker","favorites":{"color":"red","city":"San Francisco"}},
    {"name":"Tommy Jones","favorites":{"color":"blue","city":"Paris"}}
];

var cities = [];

for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
{
    var person = people[i];

    var city = person.favorites.city;

    var index = null;
    for (var n = 0; n < cities.length; n++)
    {
          var c = cities[n];
        if (c.city == city)
        {
            index = n;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index == null)
    {
        var temp = {
            city: city,
            people: [{name: person.name, favorites: [{color: person.favorites.name}]}]
        };

        cities.push(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        cities[index].people.push({name: person.name, favorites: [{color: person.favorites.color}]});
    }

}

console.log(cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the excellent [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library (its micro, just 4 kB and offers lots of mandatory useful additions to javascript).

Secondly, you say you need the following output:

```
{ "city":"Paris",
    {{"name":"John Smith","color":"orange"},
     {"name":"Tommy Jones","color":"blue"}}
}
```

This is syntactically wrong. The people is an array of objects, it should be represented as `[{ "name" : ... }]`, **not** `{{ "name" : }}`. And after `"city" : "Paris"`, you must have a key for the people, it just cannot start with `{{` after the city. So your output should look like:

```
[
  { "city" : "Paris", "people" : [{"name" : "John Smith" }, ... ] },
  { "city" : ... },
  { "city" : ... }
]
```

That aside, Your question can be solved using underscorejs as:

```
// Assume the JSON array of people is in a variable called data
// Group data by city
data_by_city = _.groupBy(data, function(person) {
  return person["favorites"]["city"]; // Data will be grouped by this key
});

// Data is now present as { "Paris" : [ people ], ... }
// Let's convert it to [{ "city" : "Paris", "people" : [ people ] ...
output = _.map(data_by_city, function(people, city) {
  return { "city" : city, "people" : people };
});
```